# Using Excel C API (XLLs)

Tags: c, excel, xll

I have been exploring Excel C API and am now good at getting multi-cell input, doing computations and outputing the result in a single cell. Now I want to output the result in multiple cells, for example:

1) Get a column range as input
2) Sort the numbers (in the cells)
3) Write the sorted numbers in a new column or the same column (in-place)

I couldn't figure out how to write the multi-cell result. I am using "Excel XLL SDK 2010" but any method you propose should be applicable in the older versions of the SDK also.

Comment: Record a macro that does the sort.  Then adapt the recorded VBA code to your C code.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://nxll.codeplex.com to simplify creating 2-dimensional OPERs. It makes it as easy as writing a VBA add-in except you can use modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you'd assign a Variant type to a Range for multi-cell assignment.  It looks like the equivalent type in the SDK is [XLOPER/XLOPER12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687869.aspx).  Not having used the SDK I couldn't tell you how to use this, but hopefully it gets you started.